# Which one is server on ssh, sender or receiver?

Tags: ssh

I am learning ssh.
Assuming I try

```
userA@pc_A:~$ ssh userB@pc_B
```

which one is the server for ssh? pc_A? or pc_B?
And in the server machine, is only the sshd working at the communication above? I am confused when I read some different instructions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic client/server terminology. You'll encounter this over and over with TCP/IP networking:

- A *server* is a process that provides a *service*. It waits for *clients* to connect to it.
- A *client* is a process that wants to use a *service*. It creates connections to a *server*.

> userA@pc_A:~$ ssh userB@pc_B

In this case, the `ssh` program that you're running is a *client*. It will make a connection to a *server* running on host pc_B. That server may be an instance of the `sshd` program, but there are other ssh server programs that people can use.

If there is an `sshd` process running on pc_A, it's not involved with connections from an ssh client on A to a server on B.

The terms "sender" and "receiver" aren't really useful here. Once the client makes a connection to the server, the client and the server will communicate in both directions through the connection. So the client sends data which the server receives, and the server sends data which the client receives.

People will use the term "server" to refer to either the program (sshd) or the computer (pc_B) which provides the service. This can be confusing, and you will sometimes have to figure out by context whether they're talking about a computer or a program.

Comment: thank you for telling me clear answer. The part of "If there ~ ..." is what I wanted to know most.